# What is the standard VESA video mode for 1920x1080x24bpp OS Dev

Tags: operating-system, vesa

I am developing a small OS and I just started using 1280x1080 video mode (mode 11Bh) for resolution. Now I want something better because mode 11Bh is a bit pressed and its ratio inst that good. So I started searching about the 1920x1080 video mode but I couldn't find it in forums and OSDev. What is the standard mode number for mode 1920x1080x24bpp and does special full access mode 81FFh have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest VESA standard recommends querying the list of supported modes and then choosing the one that fits your needs best. Hardcoded mode numbers are a thing of the past, they aren't guaranteed (some modes that you may want may not even be supported). So, that's that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to learn if there are any hardcoded versions for 1920x1080. If you dont know its OK tho

Comment: @Guestfornow816363 See the VESA document.

Comment: Can you give me a link I couldnt find the bloody document?

Comment: @Guestfornow816363 For example, [here](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/vbe3.pdf). It lists modes up to 1280x1024, nothing larger.